# Why can't I use the WSL adapter IP to access the host services ports?

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Why can't I use the WSL adapter IP to access the host services ports?

I have a proxy service running on my windows 10 host machine, and I wish to use this service in the WSL2. Many said they are in separate networks so I opened the necessary firewall ports for this proxy service.

The strange thing is, almost every post on the internet are telling me to use the "WSL adapter IP" (I mean the IP can get from `cat /etc/resolv.conf` or `ping "$(hostname).local"`). But the only way that works for me is to use Ethernet IP of the windows host. I don't know why this could happen.

I've tried the same process in different machine, but this is the first time this issue comes out.

```bash
>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::17e4:75c9:3db3:3273%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.106
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d573:2745:bd21:c798%32
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.160.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Version info：

```bash
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

> wsl --version
WSL version： 1.0.3.0
WSLg version： 1.0.47
MSRDC version： 1.2.3575
Direct3D version： 1.606.4
DXCore version： 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version： 10.0.19044.2364
```

I test it by netcat：

```bash
root in ~ took 1m14s
❯ nc -zv 172.23.160.1 7890
^C

root in ~ took 5s
❯ nc -zv 192.168.0.106 7890
Connection to 192.168.0.106 7890 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```